# HTML5 + JS Polar Scatter Charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, data-visualization, scatter-plot

Can anyone recommend existing HTMl5 / JS data visualization toolkits or lib that can help generate polar scatter charts similar to this?  Code example would be cool!

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/polar_scatter.html

Unfortunately, I have to make this work on tablets to look at live copy of data.  So no flash and I can't pre-generate this every day using matplotlib or others.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

What I end up doing something similar to:

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/transform.html

In particular the following pieces of code helps a lot:

```
var x = pv.Scale.linear(-kx, kx).range(0, w),
    y = pv.Scale.linear(-ky, ky).range(0, h);

var data = pv.range(100).map(function(i) {
    var r = .5 + .2 * Math.random(), a = Math.PI * i / 50;
    return {x: r * Math.cos(a), y: r * Math.sin(a)};
  });
```

Where r is driven by a value in DB (not random), and to draw the bubbles similar to:

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/bubble.html

set the size, title and radius based on my preference.

This will give you the weighted polar scatter chart similar to the one that matplotlib provide, whereas normal radar chart will only let you apply icon instead of weighted bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha.com's EXT.js can do this. It renders to Canvas and SVG automatically as well.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/charts/Radar.html

Comment: Thanks, but regular radar doesn't really address what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look ad [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/). They have plenty of visualization examples including scatterplots.

Comment: I'm actually using protovis to do this, but it uses x,y coordinates from one corner instead of from the center of a circle.  I'm having trouble calculating the coordinates to spread out the weight circles.  Thoughts?